# Show Datebox over Simple Dialog box

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to show a datebox over simple dialog box in my Android-phonegap application. I can see the datebox populated over simple dialog but it is blank. When I try to select the date from it, it does not show anything. It is a blank datebox structure populated on dialog box. I want to store the date selected by the user on dialog box and will use it later on. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Here is my code

```
var rhtml = '<div class="ui-grid-a">';
rhtml+= '<div class="ui-block-a" style="width:100%;">';
rhtml+= '<label><strong>'+taskMsg+'</strong></label>';
rhtml+= '</div><br><br>';
rhtml+= '<br><div class="ui-block-a" style="width:15%;float:left;margin-top:3px">';
rhtml+= '<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chkBox" value="checked" />';
rhtml+= '</div>';
rhtml+= '<div class="ui-block-b" style="width:80%">';
rhtml+= '<label for="chkBox" id="checkB1">Check to no longer display this message</label>';
rhtml+= '</div>';
rhtml+= '</div>';
rhtml+='<div class="ui-grid-c"><div class="ui-block-a" style="width:1%"></div><div class="ui-block-b" style="width:55%"><input name="ssddateD"  readonly="readonly" id="ssddateD" data-role="datebox" data-options=\'{"mode": "flipbox","pickPageTheme":"c","useDialogForceFalse":true,"focusMode": true}\'></div><div class="ui-block-c" style="width:35%;padding-left:5%" ><input name="ssdtimeS"  readonly="readonly" id="ssdtimeS" data-role="datebox" data-options=\'{"mode": "timeflipbox","pickPageTheme":"c","useDialogForceFalse":true,"focusMode": true}\'/></div><div class="ui-block-d" style="width:5%" ></div></div>';
rhtml+= "<a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#' id='simpleclose'>OK</a>";


$("#myDialog").simpledialog({
  'mode' : 'blank',
  'prompt': 'Alert',
  'forceInput': false,
  'useModal':true,
  'pickPageTheme':'c',
  'onClosed':onClose,
  'cleanOnClose': true,
  'useDialogForceFalse':true,
  'fullHTML' : rhtml
});
```

Answer (score 0):

life should be simple use this http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox1/demos/mode/flipbox.html

or my https://github.com/ngethe/jQM-DateBoxNgethe